# asp.net how to change visibility of a menu item from load function in .cs

Tags: asp.net, menu, visible

```
 <div id = "menu2" style ="position:absolute;right:400px; margin-top: -55px;">
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu2" runat="server" Height="16px" style="margin-left: 1125px" 
        Width="63px" Visible="False">
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Economics" Value="Economics" ImageUrl="~/images/dollar.png"></asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu> </div>
```

The above code is located in .aspx page. In the load function in the .cs file , how can I change the visibility of this menu?

I can change the NavigationUrl via the following statement
     Menu1.Items[0].NavigateUrl = AfeAttachment;

but I can't seem to adjust the visibility

Comment: Did you try `Menu2.Visible = true;` ?

Comment: Could you please post the method that you are using to modify the server control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste the following the code into the method you're using to change the menu's visibile attribute:

```
Menu2.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu' does not contain a definition for 'visible'

Comment: Are you adding Menu2.Visible = true; or just Menu.Visible = true; ?  One is referring to the ID of your server control and the other is referring to the Menu class.

Comment: Hey Jerreck, do you know how I could change the visibility of an item in the menu?

Comment: I believe you can access menu items with MenuID.Items[0].  The number in the square brackets is the location of the item in the menu (first item is 0).  I think you can set their visibility with Menu2.Items[0].Visible = true/false; .  Don't take my word for it, though. I'm still learning, too :)